# Qt TableView: How to get rid of the extended grey rectangle from the row headers

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

How do I get rid of grey area as seen in the image below. It seems like if the table does not fill the entire space, the grey color just extends until the end.

I coded something similar to this image in C++.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not just grey color, it's a vertical header. As I see it, your options are:

1. Get rid of the header in Designer and create your own column with numbers, not editable, of course
2. Use custom stylesheet for QHeaderView, like (example, don't know your preffered colors)

   ```
   QHeaderView::section 
   {
       background-color: transparent;
       color: black;
       font: 10pt "MS Shell Dlg 2";
   }
   ```

   It works with QTableView.

---

UPD: Try the following: set the stylesheet for QHeaderView AND it's sections if needed, like

```
     QHeaderView
     {
         background-color: white;
     }
```

This will paint your header white, no grey, like you wanted. Then you can improve the stylesheet, styling sections (probably, you'll like proper borders and all, so don't use "border: 1px solid balck", play with border-top and/or border-bottom, otherwise sections will get ugly double inner borders).

After that you can consider styling only one header or both, further improve styleshhet, but the point remains that QHeaderView and it's sections can be styled independently

Comment: I tried that and did `tableView->setStyleSheet("QHeaderView::section { /* style settings */ }");` and have the same issue. I even set the background color to red and it seems like only the data cells with data turn red but the area I circled in my question remains grey.

Comment: Maybe, style for QHeaderView itself should help? Decorate the sections yourself after resetting the header background.